# Prolog check value in list of lists

Tags: list, prolog, element

I am programming a board game and I want to check if a move is possible. To do that, I need to check if the position player is moving to is empty or has a possible value.
However, I don't know how can I do that without returning true or false.

Example:
Imagine you have this matrix, which represents a board:

```
[ [vv,vv,vv,vv,p1]
    [vv,aa,vv,vv,vv]
    [vv,vv,aa,vv,vv]
    [vv,p2,aa,vv,vv] ]
```

I want to move p2 to aa, which is not empty but it is a possible move. How can I check if it's a possible move? I have a procedure to get the element at a specific position, and I am trying to implement the procedure that checks if position I am moving at is a possible one.

Current code:

```
elementAt(Line, 1, Y, Element):- nth0(Y, Line, Element).
elementAt([Line|Tail], X, Y, Element) :- 
   Y > 1, 
   Y1 is Y-1,
   elementAt(Tail, X, Y, Element).

checkPosition(Board, X, Y):-
   elementAt(Board, X, Y, Element),
```

Now, at checkPosition, I want to check if Element equals to vv or aa. How can I do that?

Comment: `checkposition(Board, X, Y) :- nth0(X, Board, Line), nth0(Y, Line, Element), ....`  you need to check then `Element`

Comment: How about `(Element == vv ; Element == aa)`?

Comment: Now I found another problem. I am using SICStus and, when I run it, I find this error, which I can't remove:
procedure user:nth0/3 does not exist

I already added library(lists). to the code.

Comment: I've already solved the nth0 problem. @lurker, if I use your code, when it returns "no", the program stops. How can I solve this, so that it doesn't stop?

Answer (score 0):

```
% It is true, if 
% 1. X is the first element of the listoflists 
% 2. X is not first element of the listoflists, 
% however, it is a member of the first list in listoflists
% 3. X is a member of any other element in the listoflists

memberlist(X, [X|Xs]).
memberlist(X, [Y|Ys]) :- memberlist(X, Y).
memberlist(X, [Y|Ys]) :- memberlist(X, Ys).
```

I know this is posted 4 years later, hope it will be helpful to whomever runs into this answer.